# pods: Query customs posts filter by custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

Using pods, I've created a new *custom post type* named `staff_member` which contains a *field* `staff_department_relationship` of type *Relationship* that is related to a *custom taxonomy* `staff_department`.  Also note that the `staff_department_relationship` *field* is a `single select` of *format* `dropdown`.

Now I'd like to query all staff members from a particular department and have tried a lot of different things as per http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/find/ but without much success.  I sometimes get a DB error or no posts at all:

```
$params = array(
    'limit' => -1,
    // 'where' => 'staff_department_relationship.staff_department = "some_custom_taxonomy_slug"'
    'where' => 'staff_department.name = "some_custom_taxonomy_slug"'
);
$pods = pods('staff_member', $params);
```

Anyone with any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defines slug instead of name
'where' => 'staff_department.**slug** = "some_custom_taxonomy_slug"'

Code List post_type for taxonomy - PODS Wordpress

```
<?php 
$params = array( 
'limit' => -1,
'where'=>"TaxonomySlug.Slug = 'TaxonomyTermSlug'" ,
); 
$pods = pods( 'NamePostypeHere' )->find( $params ); 
if ( $pods->total() > 0 ) { 
    while( $pods->fetch() )  { 
        //reset id 
        $pods->id = $pods->id(); 
             //get the template 
        $temp = $pods->template( 'NameTemplateHere' ); 
             //output template if it exists 
        if ( isset( $temp )  ) { ?>
        <?php echo $temp; ?>
        <?php }
    } 
        //pagination 
    echo $pods->pagination(); 
} 
else {  echo 'No content found.'; }

?>
```